# How to upload apk to play store that is having more than 100 MB size?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I want to upload apk and size is more than 100 MB. I have find some tutorials / blog for that. But I am still not clear what to do with that.
 Do I need to create expansion files or it will accept the apk directly?
 **I have checked one application '`Gears & Guts`' on `Play Store` having 313 MB. And I don't think there is any expansion file in that.**

 Can anyone guide me?
 **Any help will be appricated.**

Comment: visit this for full information : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797?hl=en

Comment: please look into my answer

Comment: @Ironman I have already checked same link, but I do not know how to add / manage exapnsion files.

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade I have already checked same link, but I do not know how to add / manage expansion files.

Comment: Generially your patch file must contain the resource these can be any of resource type and the expansion file size must be upto 2GB

Answer (score 3):

This is as per the official document .https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

1. main- are those files without this your application will not going
   to run
2. patch- are those files which are additional, without this your application can run
3. expansion-version- version that you are giving to your apk, so that Expansion files of different version will not conflict

If your app needs more than **100MB of memory**, you can use expansion files to store additional APK assets. You can store two expansion files per application. **Each expansion file can be up to 2GB in size**.

**APK files have a maximum file size, based on the Android version your APK supports:**

> 100MB - APKs that target Android 2.3 and higher (API level 9-10 and
>   14+)
>
> ```
> 50MB - APKs that target Android 2.2 and lower (API level 8 or lower)
> ```
>
> Tip: Users must run Play Store version 5.2 or higher to install 100MB
>   APKs.

Expansion files are hosted at no additional cost. When possible, Google Play will download expansion files when apps are installed or updated. In some cases, your app will need to download its expansion files.

If your expansion files are larger than 100MB, users will see a warning dialog suggesting that they use Wi-Fi to download your app.
[For more detail click here.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797?hl=en)

> **Note:** The patch expansion file is semantically the same as the main
>   expansion file—you can use each file any way you want. The system does
>   not use the patch expansion file to perform patching for your app. You
>   must perform patching yourself or be able to distinguish between the
>   two files.
>
> **JOBB tool** to encapsulate and encrypt a set of resource files and subsequent patches for that set.

Comment: I know that, but how to manage expansion file ? Please give snippet / steps instead of copying paste from that site.

Comment: Follow the same steps that are in document.

Comment: If I am having 500 images, without that, my app will not work properly, how can I manage? (FYI, I don't want to show images directly from the server. That means it should be work offline.)

Comment: @JayDroider 1st time download it & keep it in cache, why you want to keep 500 images is in APK. When app is installed download it and put it in diskcache. There is no need to use the patch file as well.

Comment: Yes this is a considerable way for last option. Thanks :).